# Parent element Width of fixed position div behavior

Tags: html, css, css-position

[image]I came into this kind of strange observation, that somebody can surely help me better understand. I have a parent div.container that contains other divs. the first div.background-div have a fixed position that covers the whole window (just put it inside initialy to remove it from DOM just by removing div.container.).The strange thing is that according to devtools element (image attached) the width of div.container is 512px, but according to the hover effect the size is full window.To solve the hover problem I can take out div.background-div of div.container. But is there a way to take advantage of this using css

[image]

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.background-div {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(68, 65, 68, 0.5);
}

body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 512px;
  height: 512px;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: box-shadow 500ms ease;
}

.container:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px rgba(189, 18, 189, 0.5);
  transition: box-shadow 500ms ease;
}

.card-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  transition: 500ms ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="background-div"></div>
  <div class="letters">
    <span class="letters">Hello</span>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper" title="click-me!">
    <div class="card-container">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/512/512/?blur" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="card-container">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/512/512" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="link-it">More</a>
</div>
```

Seems that fixed position leads to non conventional behavior

Comment: Not sure what you mean. In your second screen shot, you have the background element selected.  Are you saying that when you hover anywhere, including the background, the hover state is applied to the `container`? If so, that would be expected, since the `background-div` is a child of `container`. If you don't want that, set `pointer-events: none` on the `background-div` element.

Comment: @disinfor perfect you solved my problem I have not thought about using pointer-events: none;. I agree also that it is an expected behavior but why devtools shows 512px?

Comment: Don't describe the setup so much since we can read that but just describe the ISSUE you are trying to resolve.

Comment: FWIW You appear to have too much CSS here that might be reduced if we were to know your ultimate goal here.

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss yes I made a long description (tried to be clear), actualy pointer-events:none; solves the hover question but also why devtools shows a width of 512px

Comment: but you said that `width: 512px;` so why does this cause confusion?

Comment: Are you just trying to to apply the "glow thing" effect when you mouse over the "super centered" content?

Comment: container is taking size of image but not of background-div that is what I initialy found strange actualy

Comment: I like the "glow thing" 

Comment: @Mehdi dev tools shows 512px when you're selecting the `container` because it **is** 512px wide. A fixed position child is out of document flow, so it will not affect the width of its parent. There is nothing abnormal or unconventional about this behavior. It's exactly as expected.

Comment: @disinfor thanks for your very clear and convincing response. So fixed child position is out of document flow and does not affect its parent width

Answer (score 1):

This does not really answer the question but might make the solution simpler without all that position CSS by just super-centering the image on the screen and then within the block with simpler/smaller amount of CSS:

`display: grid; place-items: center;`

So you only get the "glow" when you hover over the block you have set.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.background-div {
  background-color: rgba(68, 65, 68, 0.5);
}

.wrapper {
  width: 512px;
  height: 512px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: box-shadow 500ms ease;
}

.container:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px rgba(189, 18, 189, 0.5);
  transition: box-shadow 500ms ease;
}

.card-container {
  display: flex;
  transition: 500ms ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="background-div"></div>
  <div class="letters">
    <span class="letters">Hello</span>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper" title="click-me!">
    <div class="card-container">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/512/512/?blur" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="card-container">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/512/512" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="link-it">More</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Mark but I have the position absolute for my slider. Some css was not removed actualy for the minimal representing snippet

Comment: FWIW I can think of no reason to have to require "position absolute for my slider" if you want a responsive web page given modern CSS.